# How is the PPP protocol byte-oriented as well as bit-oriented?

Tags: network, protocol-theory, ppp

Many articles consider PPP as byte-oriented, and others mention it as bit-oriented.

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+------------
       |   Flag   | Address  | Control  | Protocol | Information
       | 01111110 | 11111111 | 00000011 | 16 bits  |      *
       +----------+----------+----------+----------+------------
               ---+----------+----------+-----------------
                  |   FCS    |   Flag   | Inter-frame Fill
                  | 16 bits  | 01111110 | or next Address
               ---+----------+----------+-----------------
```

I think the frame fields all are in byte format, and it should be clearly byte-oriented.
Can anyone say why PPP is byte-oriented as well as bit-oriented?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The header and everything else in a PPP frame is byte-aligned - and I don't see anything that is bit-oriented.

PPP doesn't provide byte alignment (there's no sync header), see [RFC 1662 section 3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1662#section-3):

> This    figure does not include bits inserted for synchronization
> (such as    start and stop bits for asynchronous links), nor any bits
> or octets    inserted for transparency.

So, byte alignment needs to be provided by the underlying physical layer, usually a serial interface.